# Finding the pressed Node's position in Hbox

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Hbox that contains a lot of rectangles. When i press the one of the Nodes in the Hbox i want it to tell me what position that rectangle is in the observablelist how can i achieve this?

the following is an attempt (however it did not work)

```
    figureRowBox.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                for (Node n : figureRowBox.getChildren()) {
                    if (n.isPressed()) {
                        System.out.println(figureRowBox.getChildren().indexOf(n));
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

Where figureRowBox is a Hbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hit test routine I use to determine which node was pressed in a HBox:

```
final HBox images = new HBox(10);
...
imageView.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    final Object selectedNode = mouseEvent.getSource();
    final int    selectedIdx  = images.getChildren().indexOf(selectedNode);

    label.setText(
      "Selected Vehicle: " + (selectedIdx + 1)
    );
  }
});
```

---

Here is a link to [complete sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5431780):

[image: selected vehicle]